# Рандомное добавление не той маски, на изображение из списка, python (pillow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, pillow

Вот мой кусок кода, с использованием tkinter и pillow. Суть в том, что есть фон и сверху на него при нажатии кнопки, поочередно и в указанные координаты накладываются другие случайные изображения, по одному из каждого списка, в формате png (имеющие прозрачный фон). Но, в строках где рандомно мне допустим выпадает `tomato_id2`, так-же рандомно выпадает маска, но уже не `tomato_id2`, а скажем `tomato_id3` и в готовом результате видны эти кривое наложение изображения и маски. И я не могу понять как правильней и проще сделать, чтобы всегда и везде было совпадение. К примеру выпало рандомно `carrot_id1` и маска выпадала соответственно `carrot_id1`, если `orange_id3` то и маска `orange_id3` и т.д.

```
background = Image.open('E:/.../background.png', 'r')

carrot_id1 = Image.open('E:/.../carrot_id1.png', 'r')
carrot_id2 = Image.open('E:/.../carrot_id2.png', 'r')
carrot_id3 = Image.open('E:/.../carrot_id3.png', 'r')

tomato_id1 = Image.open('E:/.../tomato_id1.png', 'r')
tomato_id2 = Image.open('E:/.../tomato_id2.png', 'r')
tomato_id3 = Image.open('E:/.../tomato_id3.png', 'r')

orange_id1 = Image.open('E:/.../orange_id1.png', 'r')
orange_id2 = Image.open('E:/.../orange_id2.png', 'r')
orange_id3 = Image.open('E:/.../orange_id3.png', 'r')

number_list_background = [background]
number_list_carrot = [carrot_id1, carrot_id2, carrot_id3]
number_list_tomato = [tomato_id1, tomato_id2, tomato_id3]
number_list_orange = [orange_id1, orange_id2, orange_id3]

def click():
    p1 = Image.new('RGB', (256,256), (255, 255, 255))
    p1.paste((random.choice(number_list_carrot)), (116,216), mask=(random.choice(number_list_carrot)))
    p1.paste((random.choice(number_list_tomato)), (103,120), mask=(random.choice(number_list_tomato)))
    p1.paste((random.choice(number_list_orange)), (137,115), mask=(random.choice(number_list_orange)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
random_image = mask = random.choice(number_list_carrot)    
p1.paste(random_image, (116,216), mask=mask)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Идеально. Александр, благодарю Вас!

Comment: Мой ответ идеален.